# Nvidia with Bumblebee installation for 16.04

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, 16.04

Are there any I struction for installing Nvidia and Bumblebee on 16.04? I'm trying to do a cleans install but all the procedures I've found end in a state where Ubuntu boot to low graphics mode and if you add nomodeset to the launch parameters lightdm crashes when you try to log in.

Edit: I'm just going without Bumblebee for now.

Comment: What particular card model do you have. I can provide instructions on how to install the correct proprietary driver from tty1 which needs no graphic environment because it's a text only console.

Comment: there is an issue https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/759

Answer (score 8):

Looks like someone has succeeded...
https://lenovolinux.blogspot.si/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it tomorrow!

Comment: Did this work? If no, then I won't try.

Comment: @shahensha It worked indeed. However, the guide covers installation on nvidia-361 while the repo currently contain 367; meaning you will have to replace 361 by 367 everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/bumblebee-xenial

Step 1 - Add PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon1ks/bumblebee
```

Step 2 - Fully update the system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Step 3 - Install nvidia-361 and bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends nvidia-361 nvidia-settings bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus
```

Step 4 - Add user to bumblebee group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER bumblebee
```

Step 5 - Enable bumblebeed

```
sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed
```

Step 6 - Edit */etc/modules*

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

To add 2 lines to the end of the file:

```
i915
bbswitch
```

Step 7 - Edit the bumblebee configuration file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

line 22:

```
Driver=nvidia
```

line 55:

```
KernelDriver=nvidia-361
```

line 58:

```
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-361:/usr/lib32/nvidia-361
```

line 61:

```
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-361/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

Step 8 - Reboot

Comment: I'll give this a try! I didn't think of looking on other language wikis.

Comment: Nope, low graphics mode again.

Comment: Wait it was because I used 164 instead of 161-updates. Now I'm stuck in the lightdm login loop though.

Comment: Reinstalled without ever going into low graphics mode, still have login loop.

Comment: This is bug.
Temporarily use Ubuntu Mate 16.04 or xubuntu 16.04

Comment: You don't need a ppa to install bumblebee.

Comment: @mchid , bumblebee in Ubuntu 16.04 does not support the nvidia-361 driver, so you need to use ppa for  nvidia-361

Comment: @neon1ks Would you mind backing this up with a reference because it is available from apt-get and is the same version of 361 that is available from the nvidia website.

Comment: @neon1ks one of problems is that lightdm has "gpu-manager", which rewrites xorg.conf every time lightdm restarts. If you pass boot parameter "nogpumanager" loginscreen will show, but you can't log-in

Comment: @neon1ks do you know if the bug is fixed now?

Comment: One of those cases where afterwards I realise I should have figured this out, but since I didn't, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me the installation on 16.04 worked using the following way,

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee nvidia-367 primus
```

Then, blacklist nouveau and edit the `conf` file

edit `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` - add the text:

```
blacklist nouveau
```

edit, `/etc/bumblebe/bumblebee.conf`. Here is my bumblebee configuration file:

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-367:/usr/lib32/nvidia-367
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-367/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]

KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using the open source Nouveau Drivers, you can get it working easily.

I have the **Nouveau driver installed.** (please see image: [Driver Screenshot.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tup5x9d0l20ixdm/Nouveau%20Driver.png))

To install **Bumblebee in Ubuntu 16.04 with Nouveau**, I just used the command from the 
***Advanced Setups*** Section of the Bumblebee Official Wiki page, which says:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Advanced_Setups

*"For advanced users, if you do not want to use the proprietary nvidia driver or 32-bit libraries (for example, if you are only interested in power savings), you can do a custom installation:"*

And the command is

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bumblebee
```

Reboot.

Though the section says about some more options, nothing more seemed be necessary, it started doing the job well after reboot.

Comment: Please give a brief but informative representation of those _advanced steps_ you followed in case the link gets remove or changed.

Comment: I think my edit has clarified that only one command needs to be executed.  Thank you George for your suggestion to improve answer clarity.